# Differentiation by implicit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, implicit-differentiation

Find dy/dx by implicit differentiation. 3x²+3 = ln 5xy²

This is what i did:
6x = D (ln 5x + ln y²)
But i was thinking i could also use this way:

6x = D(5xy²)/5xy²

Are both ways the same?

Comment: @AhalleySamuel: You should add parenthesis to avoid ambiguity ...

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, you are right*.

If you try the first one, we get, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (\ln 5x + \ln y^2) = \frac{1}{5x}(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(5x)) = \frac{1}{x}$$

In case of the second, we get, $$\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(5xy^2)}{5xy^2} = \frac{5y^2}{5xy^2} = \frac{1}{x}$$ yielding the same answer as before.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yea. Both ways arrive at the same results. Thanks man